# GPIO Python Library on PIDORA not available?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

[Pidora is up-to-date on 3.12.26]

sudo yum update
sudo yum install python-rpi.gpio
 **>No package available**
sudo yum install python3-rpi.gpio
 **>No package available**
sudo yum install pip-python
 **>No package available**

How do I control the GPIO on Pidora using python?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this solved the issue!

```
sudo yum install python-devel
wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
sudo pip install RPi.GPIO
# if it doesnt work then
sudo pip uninstall RPi.GPIO  
sudo pip install RPi.GPIO
```